# How to obfuscate or delete exported names in the binary

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using namespaces and classes to implement a simple calculator with add member function.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<Container::Calculator> O1 = std::make_shared<Container::Calculator>();

    auto result = O1->Add(1, 2);

    std::printf("The final result of the calculation: %d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program, the binary will contain the name of namespaces (Container) and classes (Calculator). How can I delete or remove this names from the binary? is that possible?

I am using Windows OS and MSVC compiler to implement such programs. I have enabled string pooling flag and also using size optimization to build this binary.

Comment: What compiler are you using, and how are you compiling and linking? Please [edit] your post to include this information.

Comment: I am using MSVC and windows operating system.

Comment: (for instance by using the relevant tags)

Comment: String Pooling is enabled. Size optimization selected (rather speed favor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off [RTTI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/run-time-type-information?view=msvc-160) in the project Properties / C/C++ / Language / Enable Run-Time Type Information by setting it to `No (/GR-)` removes the need to save the internal namespace and class names in the compiled binaries, and those names are no longer visible in release builds.

However, as noted on the [`/GR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gr-enable-run-time-type-information?view=msvc-160) page:

> You usually need the /GR option when your code uses dynamic_cast Operator or typeid.